# how to display searched result in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models indent and store_item when I search store_item how to display the search result on indent index page.This is my code:

## indents/new_indent:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <%=render 'item'%>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-7">
<h3>Store Item</h3>
<div class="form-group">
 <%= form_for :indent, url:{action:'search_item'}, method: :get,remote:true,html:{id: "user_form"} do |f|%>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="col-3"><%= f.select :id, StoreItem.all.collect {|b| [b.item_name,b.id]},{prompt:"Select Item"},{onchange:"$('#user_form').submit();"}%></td>
   </tr>
 <%end%>
</tbody>
</div>
</div>
<div class="search_item"></div>
```

## Search.js.erb:

```
$('.search_item').html("<%= j render 'store_item' %>");
```

## store_item.rb:

```
  def self.search_item(a)
   StoreItem.where("id LIKE ?", "%#{a}%")
  end
```

## _store_item.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-7">
      <% @storeitems.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
          <th>Unit Price</th>:
          <td><%= s.unit_price %></td>
          <br>
          <th>Batch No</th>:
          <td><%= s.batch_no%>
          <br>
          <th>Available</th>:
          <td><%= s.quantity%>
        </tr>
      <% end %>   
</div>
</div>
```

## Indent_controller:

```
class IndentsController < ApplicationController
    def index_indent
     @stores = Store.all
     @indents = Indent.all
     @search = params[:indent_id]
     @storeitems = StoreItem.search_item(@search)
    end

def search_item
 @storeitems = StoreItem.search_item(params[:indent][:id])
end

def create_indent
 @indent = Indent.new(indent_params)
 if @indent.save
    redirect_to index_indent_indents_path
 else
  render 'index_indent'
 end
end
```

## indent_index:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Indent No</th>
      <th>Store</th>
      <th>Expected Date</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Required</th>
      <th>Pending</th>
      <th>Issued Quantity</th>
      <th>Issued Type</th>
      <th>Destroy Indent</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Batch No</th>
      <th>Available</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

   <% @indents.each do |i| %>
    <tr>  
        <td><%= i.indent_no %></td>
        <td><%= @stores.name %></td>
        <td><%= i.expected_date%></td>
        <td><%= i.description %></td>
        <td><%= i.required %></td>
        <td><%= i.pending %></td>
        <td><%= i.issued_qty %></td>
        <td><%= i.issued_type %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy_indent_indent_path(i), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %></td>

        <%= render partial: 'store_item' %>
      </tr>
 <%end%>
```

Comment: Where is your index_indent.html.erb file? The index_indent method in your controller will look for and serve the index_indent.html.erb file, unless otherwise specified. So you'll need to either render the @storeitems in that file directly, or render a partial _store_item.html.erb from within the index_indent.html.erb like so:

<%= render partial: 'store_item' %>

Comment: Added indent_index page.I tried as u told me to render partial file in indent_index page but still it showing all the searched items. want i want is when i search store_item from a dropdown list  how to dispaly the searched store_item in indent_index page.

Comment: @PriyankaBabar  Did you solve the issue ?

Comment: No @Vishal i'm still working on it.On Indent form when i search store_items it display with the single value i.e is unit_price,batch_no,quantity that is correct but how can i display the same thing on indent_index page.problem is now it dispaly all the store_items on indent_index page

Comment: @PriyankaBabar I dont understand why you are doing this much of code for only showing store item. when user select any search item than the search item details will be shown . right ?

Comment: yes @Vishal I just want to dispaly store Items on indent-index page thats it.

Comment: You can easily do that by sending the store item id. like when user select any option from select box. than on change event will fire.  and through ajax it will send request to controller. it controller will find the store item. and in success of that ajax method u can replace the store item details on any div. where you want.

Comment: @PriyankaBabar  there is no need to create any js.erb method.

Comment: @PriyankaBabar Consider this example 
$('#select_establishment').on('change',function(){
        var establishment_id = $('#select_establishment').val()
        $.ajax({
          url: '/establishment_services',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {'id' : establishment_id},
          dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function(data){
           // replace the div with data

      }
    })

Comment: @Vishal.Thanks for suggestion. I'm new to rails can u please guide me. where should i write it and how?

Comment: @PriyankaBabar js code will always written in its appropriate js file. e.g. for user controller it should written in users.js .

Comment: @Vishal I tried like this -->$('#select_store_item').on('change',function(){ var store_item_id = $('#select_store_item').val() $.ajax({ url: 'store_items/index_store_item', type: 'GET', data: {'id' : store_item_id}, dataType: 'json' }).success(function(data){ <div class="search_item"> } }) but how its work.still it showing all store Items.

Comment: @PriyankaBabar Listen this is very simple. did you use git for storing your project ?

Comment: @Vishal yes i used git but not yet pushed.

Comment: @PriyankaBabar you can push the latest code on git. i will review it and solve your issue and will let you know the code

Comment: @Vishal The modal which i worked on is not yet completed so not able to pushed the code on git.can u pls help me how do i write the ajax call in js.

Comment: @PriyankaBabar Your select box has one unique id. you can check it by inspect element. you need to binding change event on that id only. do u know how to check the id of select box ?

Comment: @Vishal I have tried as u stated above but how this js is gone work. I tried like this: '$('#select_store_item_id').on('change',function(){ var store_item_id = $('#select_store_item_id').val() $.ajax({ url: '/inventory_store_items/index_store_item', type: 'GET', data: {'id' : store_item_id}, dataType: 'json' }).success(function(data){ <div class="search_item"> } })' please help me

Comment: @PriyankaBabar Did you still stuck on this point ? Follow the step. right click on select box , than select inspect element option. than you get the html of that select box. there will be different attributes like name , class ,id and etc. you have to get ID of that select box. or you can also get the class. tell me if you have any confusion. i will let you know the different step after this step

Comment: @Vishal i tried to inspect right click on drop down option after that i paste that line on notepad it displays this                                 `<option value="">select Item</option>
<option value="1">chalks</option>
<option value="2">marker pens</option>
<option value="3">Note books</option` and here i'll getting inventory_store_item_id that is correct but how will i get its inner attributes from inventory_store_items `#indent_inventory_store_item_id'

Comment: @PriyankaBabar I need the select box html line